# How to get multiple select box values using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, multi-select

How to get multiple select box values using jQuery?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

[jQuery .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val1)

```
  var foo = $('#multiple').val();
```

Answer (score 319):

Using the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function on a multi-select list will return an array of the selected values:

```
var selectedValues = $('#multipleSelect').val();
```

and in your html:

```
<select id="multipleSelect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what if u want to get `Text 1` instead of value? replace `.val()` with `.text()`?

Comment: Worth noting that a multiple select with nothing selected returns `null` rather than an empty array. This means if you’re programatically _adding_ a selected value, you have a bit of juggling to do to get it right.

Comment: Thank you! There are so many ways to get a value from an element with jQuery that it's inevitably a struggle to find the way that you're looking for.

Comment: @Leo you can add a coalesc to get around the null issue  e.g `var selectedValues = $('#multipleSelect').val() || [];`  Also worth noting it returns an array of strings.  I was comparing to an integer and getting no matches, so i added a `.toString()`.

Answer (score 26):

You can also use js map function:

```
$("#multipleSelect :selected").map(function(i, el) {
    return $(el).val();
}).get();
```

And then you can get any property of the `option` element:

```
return $(el).text();
return $(el).data("mydata");
return $(el).prop("disabled");
etc...
```

Comment: great answer, but no need to pay the extra expense of wrapping `el` as a jQuery object for every single option.  Just go straight off the DOM when it's not too weird.  You could change `$(el).val()` to just `el.value`.  Of course if you're used to jQuery or want to grab data or attributes like your other examples, jQuery isn't hurting anyone.

Comment: @KyleMit Great tip.  Just used this approach to grab a collection of hidden field values and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 26):

Just by one line-

```
var select_button_text = $('#SelectQButton option:selected')
                .toArray().map(item => item.text);
```

Output: ["text1", "text2"]

```
var select_button_text = $('#SelectQButton option:selected')
                .toArray().map(item => item.value);
```

Output: ["value1", "value2"]

If you use .join()

```
var select_button_text = $('#SelectQButton option:selected')
                .toArray().map(item => item.text).join();
```

Output: text1,text2,text3

Answer (score 12):

```
var selected=[];
 $('#multipleSelect :selected').each(function(){
     selected[$(this).val()]=$(this).text();
    });
console.log(selected);
```

Yet another approch to this problem. The selected array will have the indexes as the option values and the each array item will have the text as its value.

for example

```
<select id="multipleSelect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="abc">Text 1</option>
    <option value="def">Text 2</option>
    <option value="ghi">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

if say option 1 and 2 are selected.

the selected array will be :

```
selected['abc']=1; 
selected['def']=2.
```

Answer (score 8):

Html Code:

```
 <select id="multiple" multiple="multiple" name="multiple">
  <option value=""> -- Select -- </option>
  <option value="1">Opt1</option>
  <option value="2">Opt2</option>
  <option value="3">Opt3</option>
  <option value="4">Opt4</option>
  <option value="5">Opt5</option>
 </select>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$('#multiple :selected').each(function(i, sel){ 
    alert( $(sel).val() ); 

});
```

Hope it works

Comment: Hey Man. It works perfectly. Check it out. You should hope it. Don't give irrelevent comment..

Comment: This is an inefficient usage of jQuery. Better is approach is to preface with an ID selector like this: `$('#multiple').find(':selected')` @Prabhagaran

Comment: @YounisShah I would hardly say it is "inefficient" as the time difference is relativity nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Just use this

```
$('#multipleSelect').change(function() {
    var selectedValues = $(this).val();  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get selected values in comma separator

```
var Accessids = "";
$(".multi_select .btn-group>ul>li input:checked").each(function(i,obj)
{
    Accessids=Accessids+$(obj).val()+",";
});
Accessids = Accessids.substring(0,Accessids.length - 1);
console.log(Accessids);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you have multiple select boxes on a single page and they all have the same class which you can prefer in case of multiple rather than tracking id's:

```
$('.classname option:selected').map(function(){
    return this.value; // If you want value.
    // Or you could also do.
    return this.text; // If you want text of select boxes.
}).get(); // It will return an Array of selected values/texts.
```

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery works well for me. I use a getFormValues() function for various tasks, so it's a good place to rebuild some of the form data when it's missing.

It checks each form field to see if it's a multi-select type and if it is, rebuild the value with all of the selected options. I'm sure something similar would be needed for checkboxes too...

```
// Get form values as a key-value Object
function getFormValues(form) {
  var formData = new FormData(form[0]),
      values = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  
  // Rebuild multi-select values.
  $.each(values, function(key, value){
    var element = $(form).find(':input[name="'+key+'"]');
    if (element.is('select[multiple]')){
      values[key] = element.val();
    }
  });
  return values;
}
```

`

```
// Use with AJAX.
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  
  $.ajax({
    URL: 'http://google.com/',
    data: getFormValues(form),
    success: function(data, textStatus){
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```