# Jquery/ javascript : Select all the selected values from drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery

Select box

```
<select id="update-select" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="3">Test1 </option>
  <option value="4">Test2 </option>
  <option value="5">Test3 /option>
  <option value="6">Test4</option>
  <option value="15">Test5</option>
</select>
```

I am selecting the options from another jquery click function based on some manipulation .

(say i have selected values 3 and 4)

later i want to see the values of selected option

i tried,

```
selectedVals = $("#update-select option:selected").val() ;
alert(selectedVals) // alerts 3
```

it shows only the first value selected.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243476/how-to-get-multiple-select-box-values-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do

```
selectedVals = $("#update-select").val() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
$("#update-select option:selected").each(function(i,elem){
   alert($(elem).val());
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5jNWY/

Hope this helps!

Comment: i want values not text

Comment: A similar solution, but with pushing the values onto an array, which is probably what you're after:
http://jsfiddle.net/eN32E/