# Not getting selected value for dropdown in jquery

Tags: jquery, dropdownbox

I am trying to get selected values in dropdown. I have created dropdown. But I dont know how to get selected values in jquery?

My code HTML:

```
<select id="demo" multiple="multiple">
    <option id="test1" value="Javascript">Javascript</option>
    <option id="test2" value="Python">Python</option>
    <option id="test3" value="LISP">LISP</option>
    <option id="test4" value="C++">C++</option>
    <option id="test5" value="jQuery">jQuery</option>
    <option id="test6" value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#demo').multiselect(); // here I need to get selected values.
```

I have used http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect.html this for dropdown

Comment: possible duplicate of [how-to-get-multiple-select-box-values-using-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243476/how-to-get-multiple-select-box-values-using-jquery)

Comment: You should search before asking.... tons of answers in stackoverflow and even more in google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$('#demo :selected').each(function (i, selected) {
    console.log(selected.value)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selected_val=[];

$('#demo').multiselect({
    onChange : function(option, checked) {
            var sel=[];
            $('#demo :selected').each(function(i,selected) {
                 sel.push(selected.value);
            });
            selected_val=sel;
           alert(selected_val);
   }
});
```

Hope it helps....