# Chosen js is not marking options as selected

Tags: form-submit, jquery-chosen

I put a multi select list box on MVC form and setup chosen js, I'm able to select options but when i submit the form no values are submitted, when i checked the markup i came to know selected options are not marked as selected, so what expect is below

```
<option value="1">Test 1</option>
<option value="2" selected>Test 2</option>
<option value="3" selected>Test 3</option>
```

But what i can see is as in attached picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chosen won't add the `selected` attribute to your html. If you need to find out what values were selected, use `$(selector).val()`.

See below for example. In this example, I am initializing a chosen multiselect and assigning it's selected values to some output to demonstrate `$(selector).val()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chosen-select").chosen();

  $(".chosen-select").on("change", function() {
    let chosenVal = $(".chosen-select").val();
    $("#out").text(chosenVal);
  });
});
```

```css
.chosen-select {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple="">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
</select>

<p id="out"></p>
```

Comment: thanks, rather than showing in text box, whenever user selects/unselect an option can we mark options as selected in select/list box?

Comment: They are selected in the box, i was just showing you how to get the selected values. They just don't have the `selected` tag because I guess that's how chosen works. Or do you mean you want to not have the selected options moved to the top, and rather have something like a dropdown with a list of checkboxes?