# Get values in multiple select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've been trying to get the values in a multiple select box and put it in an array. I've tried this:

JQUERY

```
var selectedValues = $('#multipleSelect').val();
```

HTML

```
<select id="multipleSelect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

By Darin Dimitrov from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243476/how-to-get-multiple-select-box-values-using-jquery).

I was wondering if there was a way to get all the values in the multiple select box without having to select anything.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('#multipleSelect option').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr(‘value’);
    // push the value to an array
});
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to `map` and `get` the values

```js
var values = $("#multipleSelect option").map(function(){return this.value}).get();

//console.log( values );
alert( values );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="multipleSelect" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1">Text 1</option>
   <option value="2">Text 2</option>
   <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this is what I need. uhm, how i can display the values in say an alert box? i cant for the life of me figure out

Comment: @Mel, you can just use `alert()`. I updated the example. But it is better to use `console.log` for debugging.

Comment: What id are you using on your `multiple` html @Mel ?

Comment: I'm using `call_Prod` as an id. I did change the `#multipleSelect` to that when I tried but I get an empty alert box

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle.com of your code? If it is not working, it means that there is something wrong with the your implementation. The code above should work.  @Mel

Comment: I figured it was something I was doing wrong. Thank you for bearing with me. The jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/cn4c8nsx/13/

Comment: @Mel I think the issue was, you are running the code before all the html code was loaded. Why don't you use `jQuery` event listener instead of `onclick`