# Show input field only if a specific option is selected in multiple select

Tags: javascript, html

I have a multiselect box like the example below

```
<select name="geolocation_country[]" class="form-control form-control-chosen" id="geolocation_country" data-placeholder="Please select..." multiple>
                                <option  value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
                                <option  value="IN">India</option>
                                <option  value="DZ">Algeria</option>
                                <option  value="DS">American Samoa</option>
                                <option  value="AD">Andorra</option>
                                <option  value="AO">Angola</option>
                                <option  value="AI">Anguilla</option>
                                <option  value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
                                <option  value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                                <option  value="AR">Argentina</option>
                                <option  value="AM">Armenia</option>
                                <option  value="AW">Aruba</option>
                                <option  value="AU">Australia</option>
                                <option  value="AT">Austria</option>
                                <option  value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
                                <option  value="BS">Bahamas</option>
</select>
```

Now, if I select India along with someother countries, I need another multiple select for indian states shown

```
<div id="show_geolocation_region">
<select name="geolocation_region[]" class="form-control form-control-chosen" id="geolocation_region" data-placeholder="Please select..." multiple>
            <option selected value="no">Target all states of India</option>
                                <option  value="1">Andaman & Nicobar Islands</option>
                                <option  value="2">Andhra Pradesh</option>
                                <option  value="3">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
                                <option  value="4">Assam</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I created a js for normal select :

```
$("#geolocation_country").on('change', function() {
    if(this.value == "IN") {
        alert('India clicked');
        $("#show_geolocation_region").show();           
    } else  {
        $("#show_geolocation_region").hide();           
    }

});
```

If I select India alone, then the states select box shows. But If I select India along with other countries, the states search box disappears.
Is it possible to create a JS where you show states box for india if india is selected in country? Regardless of other countries selected or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val1) to [get all selected values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3243476/10245948) instead of DOM's plain `.value`.

Then apply the array methods `.includes` or `.indexOf` to check whether the value `"IN"` has been selected.

Comment: So replace `this.value == "IN"` for `$(this).val().indexOf("IN") > 0`

Comment: Can you please modify the js code to make this answer a bit more elaborate?

Comment: Umm. That didn't work for me. Nothing happens if I select India.

Comment: @David: it should be `.indexOf("IN") >= 0`

Comment: Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/028gfwk5/

Answer (score 0):

Use `onchange="showSelectedValues(this);"` on selector elment id="geolocation_country"

Then use this:

```
function showSelectedValues(self){
  let selectedValues = Array.from(self.selectedOptions)
    .map(option => option.value);
  console.log(selectedValues);      
}
```

It will give you values in array on that you can loop over and put your condtion for hide and show.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to have array of `countries` objects with their `states`, does not matter you get these values from AJAX request or create statically. and on select create new select and append selected element into `$('#show_geolocation_region')` or whatever. Please Check [this link](https://codepen.io/shakogele/pen/XxVWNZ) :):

```
var countries = [
  {
    name: 'Afghanistan',
    value: 'AF',
    states: [
      {
        name: 'State 1',
        value: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'State 2',
        value: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'State 3',
        value: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'India',
    value: 'IN',
    states: [
      {
        name: 'Andaman & Nicobar Islands',
        value: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Andhra Pradesh',
        value: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'Arunachal Pradesh',
        value: 3
      },
      {
        name: 'Assam',
        value: 4
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Your HTML:

```
<select name="geolocation_country[]" class="form-control form-control-chosen" id="geolocation_country" data-placeholder="Please select..." multiple>
</select>
<div id="show_geolocation_region">
</div>
```

Your JQUery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var select = $("#geolocation_country");
  countries.forEach(function(country){
    var option = $('<option/>');
    option.attr({ 'value': country.value }).text(country.name);
    select.append(option);
  })
});

$("#geolocation_country").on('change', function() {
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();
  $('#show_geolocation_region').html('');
  selectedValue.forEach(function(countryValue){
    var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('#show_geolocation_region');
    sel.attr('multiple', true);
    sel.attr('name', 'geolocation_region_'+countryValue);
    sel.attr('id', 'statesSelect');
    sel.attr('class', 'form-control form-control-chosen');
    var selectedCountry = countries.find(function(country){
      return country.value = countryValue;
    });
    selectedCountry.states.forEach(function(state){
      sel.append($("<option>").attr('value',state.value).text(state.name));
    })

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#geolocation_country").on('change', function() {
    if($(this).value == "IN") {  //Change here
        alert('India clicked');
        $("#show_geolocation_region").show();           
    } else  {
        $("#show_geolocation_region").hide();           
    }

});
```