# Get current option in multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the current selected/unselected in a Jquery `multiselect`?

I already know how to get the selected values in a `multiselect`. The problem is that I need to get the one that was currently selected/unselected when the user clicked on it. It looks like a trivial question but I haven't really found a proper solution so far.

This is what I previously tried:

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
   var element = $(this).val();
})
```

Unfortunately it returns an array with all selected options. What I need is to get the current either selected or unselected value by the user. I just tried to create a method myself using auxiliar variables and it seems that it works now.

```
    if($(this).attr('id').includes('Type')) Key = "trackertype";

    if(selectedValue.length > 0 && $(this).val() == null){
        Value = selectedValue[0].toString();
        selectedValue = [];
        Key = '-' + Key;
    }else if(selectedValue.length == 0 && $(this).val() != null){
        selectedValue.push($(this).val()[0]);
        Value = selectedValue[0].toString();
    }else if(selectedValue.length > 0 && $(this).val() != null && selectedValue.length < $(this).val().length){
        var selected = true;
        $.each($(this).val(),function(i,item){
            var current = item.toString();
            $.each(selectedValue,function(i,itemV){
                if(current != itemV.toString()){
                    Value = current.toString();  
                    selectedValue.push(current.toString());  
                    selected = false;                                   
                }
            });
        });
    }else if(selectedValue.length > $(this).val().length){
        $.each($(this).val(),function(i,item){
            var current = item.toString();
            $.each(selectedValue,function(i,itemV){
                if(current != itemV.toString()){
                    Value = itemV.toString();  
                    selectedValue = jQuery.grep(selectedValue, function(value) {
                        return value != itemV.toString();
                    });
                    selected = true;                                   
                }
            });
        });
    }
    if(selected){
        Key = '-' + Key;
    }
```

I needed to send Value(value of the current selected option) and Key(select Name) to a web service. Its not the best possible code(sorry about that) but it actually does its job.

Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get multiple select box values using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243476/how-to-get-multiple-select-box-values-using-jquery)

Comment: Yes i have tried by using $('#selectId').val(), but this returns an array of the selected values. I do only need THE LAST ONE that was selected/unselected by the user.

Comment: @CarlosIS you may want to [edit] your question and include some code with that info from comment. Have you tried adding click listener on options?

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectedItems =  document.querySelectorAll('#selectBoxid option:checked');
// here selectboxid is id of select element of your page.
```

It is simple when any html element can get using `document.getElementsById('id')`.

Just same as if you want to get html element using css class or any css selector rather than id of element or name of html element.

For example :

```
<p class="text-center" > abcd </p>
```

Then, we can retrive all html using:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.text-center')
```

Same in given example we want option html element which is selected for that property I use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('option:checked');
```

Comment: it is simple when any html element can get using document.getElementsById('id').

Comment: I've meant to explain it in your answer... You can edit it anytime!

Comment: it is simple when any html element can get using "document.getElementsById('id')". just same as if you want to get html element using css class or any css selector rather than id of element or name of html element.    example : <p class="text-center" > abcd </p> than we can retrive all html using "queryselectorAll('.text-center')".                                                              same in given example we want option html element which is selected for that property i use "document.querySelectorAll('option:checked');

Comment: Write this in your answer... Click *edit*, and you can edit it. Don't write the details in comments, not everybody reads them...

Comment: Your edit [**was** performed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57267802/revisions). I've edited it again, making it even better. Thank you for your time, this way you can help to more people, and your answer will probably get more upvotes.