# How do I display multi selected values in a div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to display the values I get from a multi select to an empty div using jquery. 
For example, in the code below, how would I implement this using jquery?

```html
<select multiple data-style="bg-white rounded-pill px-4 py-3 shadow-sm" class="selectnumber w-100 multiple searchable='Search here..'">
  <option>23</option>
  <option>17</option>
  <option>14</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>9</option>
</select>

<div class="numberselected">
  numbers selected should display here...
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you are using some library wrapper for multiselect. What lib is it?

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243476/how-to-get-multiple-select-box-values-using-jquery

Comment: I am using select2, a jquery plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have option values, so i will show 2 variants.

```js
$('#my-select').change(function(){
  //Get selected options
  let selectedOptions = $(this).children('option:selected');
  
  //Get text of selected options
  let textValues = selectedOptions
    .map(function(){return $(this).text()})
    .toArray();
    
  //Get values of selected options
  let valValues = selectedOptions
    .map(function(){return $(this).val()})
    .toArray();
    
  //Show them in divs
  $('#show-by-text').html(textValues.join(','));
  $('#show-by-value').html(valValues.join(','));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="my-select">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<br>
By text:
<div id="show-by-text">
</div>
By value:
<div id="show-by-value">
</div>
```

Comment: Just FYI if there is no `value` attribute, then the text is used. The `value` is always set regardless.

Answer (score 2):

**You can do something below**

```js
$(document).on('change', '.selectnumber', function(e){

var selected =   $('.selectnumber').val();
$('.numberselected').text(selected);


//console.log(selected);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple data-style="bg-white rounded-pill px-4 py-3 shadow-sm"
                        class="selectnumber w-100 multiple searchable='Search here..'">
                        <option>23</option>
                        <option>17</option>
                        <option>14</option>
                        <option>11</option>
                        <option>9</option>
                    </select><!-- End -->
                    <div class="numberselected">
                         //numbers selected should display here. 
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use jQuery I hope the below code will resolve your issue. Let me know if it didn't work.

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <select multiple data-style="bg-white rounded-pill px-4 py-3 shadow-sm" class="selectnumber w-100 multiple searchable='Search here..'" id="multi-select">
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
  </select><!-- End -->
  <div class="numberselected"> 
   //numbers selected should display 
  </div>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#multi-select")
    .change(function() {
      var str = "";
      $("#multi-select option:selected").each(function() {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
      });
      $(".numberselected").text(str);
    })
    .change();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery` `change` event.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#multi").change(function(){
    $("#numberselected").text($("#multi").val())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple data-style="bg-white rounded-pill px-4 py-3 shadow-sm"
    id="multi" class="selectnumber w-100 multiple searchable='Search here..'">
    <option>23</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>9</option>
</select>
<div class="numberselected" id="numberselected">
    numbers selected should display here...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JQ:

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').on('change', function() {
      console.log( $(this).val() );
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: null -->

        <select id ="test" multiple data-style="bg-white rounded-pill px-4 py-3 shadow-sm" class="selectnumber w-100 multiple searchable='Search here..'">
          <option>23</option>
          <option>17</option>
          <option>14</option>
          <option>11</option>
          <option>9</option>
        </select>
```