# jQuery - Filtering table rows using an array of class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, tablefilter

I have a table with some values and a filter option where the user can select multiple values and filter the table. What I am trying to achieve is to have a filter with numbers from 1 to 10, and table `tr` with class names `filter_1`, `filter_2`, `filter_3` etc. when I choose number 1 from filter and click on it, it will show only tr with class `filter_1`.
My code is below.

HTML:

```
<select multiple id="filterNumber">
<option value="1">1</option><option value="1">2</option><option value="1">3</option>
</select>
<button class="filterBtn">Filter</button>
```

Table:

```
<table>
<thead><tr><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="filter_1"><td>A</td></tr>
<tr class="filter_5"><td>B</td></tr>
<tr class="filter_1"><td>C</td></tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','.filterBtn',function(){
let filterNumber = $('#filterNumber).val();

//loop through this numbers and hide tr without this class name 
});
```

I know how to pass these values through AJAX into DB and display the result, but I am trying to learn more like doing from the front-end only that makes my app more faster.
But I don't know how to filter this using JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: well your jQuery has a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all the thdboy rows and hide them.
Select all the rows with the class and show them

```js
$(document).on("click", '.filterBtn', function() {

  const filterNumber = $('#filterNumber').val();

  // create a comma seperated list of the class names to show
  var filters = filterNumber.map(function (num) {
    return '.filter_' + num
  }).join()
  
  var trs = $('table tbody tr') // select all the rows

  // if we have filters run the code
  if (filters.length) {
    trs
      .hide() // hide them
      .filter(filters) // find the rows with the class[es]
        .show() // show them
   } else {
     // no filters, just show everything
     trs.show()
   }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="filterNumber">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="filterBtn">Filter</button>


<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="filter_1">
      <td>A1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_1">
      <td>A2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_5">
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter_3">
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much..you made my day happy...#happycoding

Answer (score 0):

Add `hideable` or similar so you don't select the wrong thing.

```
<table>
<thead><tr><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="filter_1 hideable"><td>A</td></tr>
<tr class="filter_5 hideable"><td>B</td></tr>
<tr class="filter_1 hideable"><td>C</td></tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Hide them all, then show the visible one(s):

```
$(document).on('click','.filterBtn',function(){
  const filterNumbers = $('#filterNumber').val().toArray().map(item => item.value);

   $('.hideable').addClass( "hidden" ); 

  filterNumbers.forEach(num => 
    $(`.filter_${number}`).each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("hidden"); 
    })
  )
}
```

You need to add a class to your CSS with `display:none` for `.hidden`

Multi-select values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55929605/1758461

jQuery `each()`: https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function

Comment: FYI it is a multiple select and there is no reason to use each to remove a class

Answer (score 0):

On the click of your button, you take the desired value, as you did. After that, you can use jQuery to add `hide` class to each `tr` that does not have the filtered class, with `tr:not(.className)`, as shown in the example below:

```
$(document).on('click', '.filterBtn', function(){
 let filterNumber = $('#filterNumber').val();
 let className = 'filter_' + filterNumber;
 $('table tbody tr:not(.'+className+')').addClass('hide');
});
```

Note that if you filter more than once, you will also need to include a way to remove the hide class if you've previously filtered something else. So you would just add

```
$('table tr.'+className+'').removeClass('hide');
```

to remove hide class if the filter element has been **previously** filtered out.

**Edit:**

Since this is a multiple select, I would first apply `hide` class to each element, then loop through selected values and remove `hide` from the ones whose class matches the selected number.

```
$(document).on('click', '.filterBtn', function(){
   $('table tbody').find('tr').addClass('hide');
   let filterNumbersArray = $('#filterNumber').val();
   for(i=0; i<filterNumbersArray.length; i++){
      let className = 'filter_' + filterNumbersArray[i];
      $('table tbody tr.'+className+'').removeClass('hide');
   }
});
```

Comment: FYI it is a multiple select

Answer (score 0):

If your rows have classes associated with the selection values, then you can use classes to select which rows to hide and show.
Notice how I select all the rows first to remove the class *hide*. Then, I add *hide* to all rows that do not share the glass selected.

```
     jQuery("#c_selector").change(function(){
        jQuery('table tbody tr').removeClass('hide');
        var cat_id = jQuery("#c_selector option:selected").val();
        console.log(cat_id)
        jQuery('table tbody tr:not(.itemtext.c_id'+cat_id+')').addClass('hide');
    })
```

Maybe this is helpful to someone!