# Copy selected multiple values to the text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I have drop down list as below.

```
     <select id="checkOwner" multiple="multiple" onchange="copyValue()">
       <option value="FIRSTNAME">First Name</option>
       <option value="LASTNAME">Last Name</option>
     </select>
```

I used Below javascript to add checkbox

```
$(function() {
  $('#checkOwner').multiselect({
   });  
});
```

I used below javascript to copy selected value to text field.

```
function copyValue() {
  var dropboxvalue = document.getElementById('checkOwner').value;
  document.getElementById('mytextbox').value = dropboxvalue;
}
```

But the problem is, this copy only one value. I want to copy all the selected values. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get multiple select box values using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243476/how-to-get-multiple-select-box-values-using-jquery)

Comment: @Joundill I tried. But it's not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the option and put selected values in a string and then output the string on the textbox

```
function copyValue() {

  var str = "";
  for (var option of document.getElementById('checkOwner').options) {
    if (option.selected) {
      str+= option.value+" ";
    }

    document.getElementById('mytextbox').value = str;
  }
}
```

Comment: What happened to the answer?

Comment: can you help me for another problem. I have two drop downs. When i select value from one dropdown another selected value disappear from textfield. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Please post more details about it and i will help you. if you added a new question it will be fine.

Comment: I posted a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62144811/copy-selected-multiple-values-to-the-textbox-from-more-than-one-drop-down

Answer (score 0):

my approach is loop on the options then check the condition if isSelected

html

```
<select name="checkOwner" multiple="multiple" onchange="copyValue(this)">
```

js

```
const copyValue = me => {
    let y = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('select option')).map(x => x.selected ? x.value : '')
    document.getElementById('mytextbox').value = y.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: it's print -1-1-1 end of the array

Comment: do you have multiple selectbox on that page ?