# Copy selected multiple values to the textbox from more than one drop down

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, checkboxlist

I have tow drop downs as below.

```
<select id="checkOwner"  multiple="multiple" onchange="copyValue1(this)">
       <option value="FirstName">First Name</option>
       <option value="SecondName">Last Name</option>
      </select>
      <select id="checkMember" multiple="multiple" onchange="copyValue2(this)>
       <option value="FirstName">First Name</option>
       <option value="SecondName">Last Name</option>
      </select>
```

I have below javascript to print selected multiple values from dropdowns.

```
function copyValue() {

  var str = "";
  for (var option of document.getElementById('checkOwner').options) {
if (option.selected) {
  str+= option.value+" ";
}

document.getElementById('mytextbox').value = str;
  }
}

function copyValue2() {

  var str = "";
  for (var option of document.getElementById('checkMember').options) {
if (option.selected) {
  str+= option.value+" ";
}

document.getElementById('mytextbox').value = str;
  }
}
```

The problem is when I select values from first that value print in text box. But I select value from second dropdown First printed values disappeared and second dropdown box values are printed. But I want to keep all and when I untick I want to remove this value also. How can I do this.

Comment: Do you accept duplicates in your textbox, something like firstname lastname lastname firstname?

Comment: @Hardood yes accept duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you accepting duplicate values then, this is the solution:
I updated your HTML code to suit your needs by adding real values to your dropdown lists instead of using "FirstName,LastName".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="checkOwner" multiple="multiple" onchange="copyValue()">
       <option value="John">John</option>
       <option value="Abeer">Abeer</option>
     </select>
    <br>

    <select id="checkMember" multiple="multiple" onchange="copyValue2()">
       <option value="Doe">Doe</option>
       <option value="Trump">Trump</option>
       <option value="Abeer">Abeer</option>
     </select>
    <br>
     <input type="text" name="mytextbox" id="mytextbox" size="200">

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getOld(currentSelect)
{
  var x = [];
  for (var option of document.getElementById(currentSelect).options) {
   if (option.selected) {

       x.push(option.value);
     }
   }

   return x;
}

function copyValue() {

  x = getOld('checkMember');
  y = [];
  for (var option of document.getElementById('checkOwner').options) {
    if (option.selected) {
          y.push(option.value);
    }
    else
    {
        y = y.filter(value => value != option.value );
    }
  }
  x = x.concat(y);
   document.getElementById('mytextbox').value = x.join(' ');
}



function copyValue2() {
  x = getOld('checkOwner');
  y = [];
  for (var option of document.getElementById('checkMember').options) {
   if (option.selected) {
      y.push(option.value);
   }
    else
    {
        y = y.filter(value => value != option.value );
    }
  }
    x = x.concat(y);
   document.getElementById('mytextbox').value = x.join(' ');
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: If I untick value it is not removed since selected value save in "var old"

Comment: You said you want to keep all.

Comment: I want to remove value once I untick.

Comment: I edited the question. What I want is I want to print selected value in text box. But when I untick, selected value should be disappear.

Comment: is there way to we keep another existing text with dropdown selected values within text field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215152/discussion-between-hardood-and-dinu).