# How to escape the apostrophe in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-plugins

When I select a name from dropdown where it has an apostrophe
Example: Brian O'Connar

My JS code will bring Brian O and rest of the characters after apostrophe  gets cuts.

My Original JS code to load the data --

```
else if(newClaimCols[key]== "assigned_to_full_name_primary") {
  var selectedText =$("#claim" + newClaimCols[key] + "filter").val() 
  //Brian O

  if (selectedText!==null && selectedText!=="" ) {
    var temp1 = $("#claim" + newClaimCols[key] + "filter").val();
    for (var key in temp1) {
      temp.push(temp1[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

In above case .val() selects only the text before apostrophe

2nd case
I tried .text() please refer below code

```
else if (newClaimCols[key] == "assigned_to_full_name_primary") {
  var selectedText = $("#claim" + newClaimCols[key] + "filter option:selected").text();//Brian O'Connar
  if (selectedText!==null && selectedText!=="" ) {
    var temp1 =$("#claim"+newClaimCols[key]+ "filter option:selected").text();
    temp.push(temp1);
  }
}
```

In this case i am getting Brian  O'Connar  but if i select multiple names  Brian O'Connar and Nishinoya'O in dropdown it comes like

Example: Brian O'ConnarNishinoya'O

not sure how to handle this.

Please let me know how can i completely load the name with the apostrophe or a solution for 2nd case  .text() when multiple name gets selected.

Comment: It's unclear why your first `.val()` is giving truncated values - most likely your HTML is malformed.

Comment: To get multiple values from a `<select multiple` use .val() - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243476/how-to-get-multiple-select-box-values-using-jquery).

Comment: Using `.text()` on multiple elements (in your case multiple `<option>`) will always merge the texts together into a single text.  Don't use `.text()` on multiple elements unless you know what it does and why.  If you're using `option:selected` then use `.map` to get the values.

Comment: Please provide enough code (HTML) to be able to determine the cause of your first issue.  `.val()` should return multiple values in an array.  See [mcve].

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181514/freedomn-m I got an idea that my HTML was wrong not js

Answer (score 0):

To properly handle the apostrophe and preserve the complete name, you can use JavaScript's `encodeURIComponent()` function to encode the selected text before pushing it into the `temp` array. This will ensure that the apostrophe (and any other special characters) are correctly escaped. By encoding the selected text using `encodeURIComponent()`, you can safely pass it as a parameter or store it in an array without any issues. When you need to use the value later, you can decode it using `decodeURIComponent()`.I added it to the code, I hope this solves your problem.

```
else if (newClaimCols[key] == "assigned_to_full_name_primary") {
  var selectedText = $("#claim" + newClaimCols[key] + "filter option:selected").text();
  if (selectedText !== null && selectedText !== "") {
    var temp1 = $("#claim" + newClaimCols[key] + "filter option:selected").text();
    temp.push(temp1);
  }
}
```

Comment: var temp1 =$("#claim"+newClaimCols[key]+ "filter option:selected").text();
this line is already picking up the name with escape character but when multiple names are selected Example-- Brian O'Connar and Nishinoya'Shoyo then result would be  Brian O'ConnarNishinoya'O this was the 2nd case i mentioned , do you have anything in your mind where i can get multiple names gets with space or any other character.

Comment: In that case, you can directly push the temp1 value into the temp array without any modifications, updated code in my initial response

Comment: temp1=Brian O'ConnarNishinoya'O has two names mergerd together  how can i split it?? i need two names separated as Brian O'Connar  Nishinoya'O

Comment: have you tried using ```split()``` with a delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up my HTML option tag
from this

```
optstring += "<option value='" + key +'='+  val + "'>" +val+ "</option>";
```

to this

```
optstring += '<option value="' + key +'='+  val + '">' +val+ "</option>";
```

Now the value from html i am getting to JS is accepting apostrophe